# How to loop through elements in XML to shred and load to database

Tags: xml, xpath, pentaho, kettle, spoon

I have a requirement where an incoming XML has to be shredded and loaded into database.
All elements have their respective tables.
Incoming XML looks something like this:

```
<root>
  <creditreport>
    <data1>
      <A>val1</A>
      <B>val2</B>
    </data1>
    <data2>
      <C>val3</C>
      <D>val4</D>
    </data2>
    <data3>
     <E>val5</E>
     <F>val6</F>
    </data3>
    <data3>
     <G>val7</G>
     <H>val8</H>
    </data3>
  </creditreport>
</root>
```

Now In Kettle I am designing a generic framework that would fetch the XML and shred it into database.
I am using 'Get XML Data' Component to read XML.
I have defined 'loop Xpath' as root/creditreport and then I have read fields one-by-one something as:

```
name   xpath   Element  ResultType 
 A      data1   Node     Valueof 
 B      data1   Node     Valueof 
 ..... 
 .....
 .....
 E     data3    Node     Valueof
 .....
 ..... 
 G     data3    Node     Valueof
```

But the problem is, it's shredding only first row for  and missing the second one. I can understand the reason as XPATH loop is only till . 
If I define 'xpath loop' as 'root/creditreport/data3' then problem for element 'data3' gets resolved but there are other elements too which can repeat and then I would be standing again at the starting point of my problem.

Any advice!!

Comment: Do you mean the second "creditreport" record is not processed or the second row of DataX elements?

Comment: @Cyrus Second row of data DataX elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both parent (dataX) and child nodes (A,B,C,etc) are really unique/sequential you can make one very generic setup:

Use `/root/creditreport/*/*` as the xpath loop path

Set up the fields like this manually:

[image: Field definitions in Get Data from XML]

That should get you an output like this:

[image: Output sample]

From here you can denormalize or otherwise process your data as you wish. Note that I've added a sequence number for the nodes at the parent level, so you can distinguish the first Data3 from the second, etc.

If on the other hand your dataX nodes all have the same child nodes (A,B A,B rather than A,B C,D etc), you can use `/root/creditreport/*` as the xpath loop path and skip the parent node field, configuring your value node A and B normally.

Here are the definitions and output. All fields are defined relative to the current node (.).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow!! Just what I wanted. You rock!!

Comment: @Cyrus-Just one small question. When I am opting for second option given in your solution i.e. setting /root/creditreport/* and configuring nodes normally, few blank rows are also coming apart from requisite rows. Any idea!!

Comment: For example that I metioned above in my question, if <data4> has two entries too along with <data3>, then output is coming as two required rows for <data3> and two blank rows. and similarly for <data4> too.

Comment: I've added pics with my config for the second case, though I used A-H to show your sample data in full. Make sure there are no references to Data3 or Data4 in any field definition, it should all be relative. If this doesn't help, maybe add a screenshot with your sample data/preview?

Comment: @Cyrus- Done. Because of your help I learnt few new things today.

Comment: @Cyrus..one doubt..How to fetch elements under <creditreport> and at the level of <data*>. Since XPATH defined till elements under <data*>. For example if just before <data1> in the above example I have <sampledata>test</sampledata>. How to get this value along with others.

Comment: That could be very simple or very involved, depending on the structure. If there is a single element, it's easy, you just use parent syntax and add a field with ../sampledata/test as xpath. If there are multiple records, things get complicated, because even if you use tokens to link data* to sampledata*, you are stuck with the duplicates. I'd split the XML into one stream per section then.

Comment: @Cyrus..One small doubt. With the current solution that you proposed above how to access <data4><X>datax</X></data4> that comes inside any <DATA*>. I tried by increasing '/*' to access one more level of depth but then I am loosing previous levels of data. Can you help!!!

Comment: @vikas It's difficult to imagine your data structure. Can you post more details?